# Различия между random и math.random

Tags: java, генерация-случайных-данных

Есть ли разница между :

```
Random gen = new Random();
//цикл 
{massive[i]=gen.nextInt(1000);}
```

и

```
//цикл
massive[i]=(int)(Math.random()*1000);
```

?
И что когда лучше использовать? Я так понимаю , что из-за приведения типов , второй метод будет заметно медленнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый вариант выглядит более эстетично и отсутствует приведение типов. А если в общем, то оба метода равнозначны. Если посмотреть реализацию Math.random() то увидим следующее:

```
 private static final class RandomNumberGeneratorHolder {
    static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
}
public static double random() {
    return RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: только вот вопроизвести результат не получится. А с Random можно. И если много потоков, то Math.random точно не надо использовать.

Comment: Интересно, а почему Math.random нельзя использовать в многопоточном окружении, а Random можно? Они же не thread-safe. Применяют для этого безопасную версию - LocalThreadRandom